# Приведение строки к nullable int типу

Tags: c#, .net, типы-данных

Подскажите, можно ли без написания функций привести строку к ?int типу ?

Попытался найти решения, но в основном натыкался на самописные функции преобразования.

Неужели средствами самого C# нельзя выполнить подобные преобразования?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте `int.Parse`. Или `int.TryParse`, если строка имеет законное право быть не строковым представлением числа.

Скорее всего, вам понадобится [вариант с указанием языка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f56zcx39%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `int.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvatiantCulture)` или `int.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvatiantCulture, out result)`.

Для случая nullable-типа, если вам нужно получить `null` при ошибке преобразования, придётся-таки вручную:

```
int temp;
int? result = int.TryParse(s, out temp) ? temp : default(int?);
```